# Display an alert dialog on lock screen on Android

Tags: android, android-service, android-dialog

I have a device admin application where the administrator can lock the device remotely. We want to be able to show an alert dialog to the user on top of the lock screen.

I know that it is possible to show an activity however we are only interested in showing an alert dialog.

Also I know that there is lock screen notifications in Lollilop, but we want to support older OS versions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Set  permission in manifest `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`and  use `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` in your code.